# Colour palette from low to high for every row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a geom_tile plot for a dataset, where I need to highlight the max and min values in every row (colour palette going from green to red)

```
Dataset:
    draft_mean trim rf_pwr
 1        12.0  1.0  12253
 2        12.0  0.8  12052
 3        12.0  0.6  12132
 4        12.0  0.4  12280
 5        12.0  0.2  11731
 6        12.0  0.0  11317
 7        12.0 -0.2  12126
 8        12.0 -0.4  12288
 9        12.0 -0.6  12461
 10       12.0 -0.8  12791
 11       12.0 -1.0  12808
 12       12.2  1.0  12346
 13       12.2  0.8  12041
 14       12.2  0.6  12345
 15       12.2  0.4  12411
 16       12.2  0.2  12810
 17       12.2  0.0  12993
 18       12.2 -0.2  12796
 19       12.2 -0.4  12411
 20       12.2 -0.6  12342
 21       12.2 -0.8  12671
 22       12.2 -1.0  13161


ggplot(dataset, aes(trim, draft_mean)) +
 geom_tile(aes(fill=rf_pwr), color="black") +
 scale_fill_gradient(low= "green", high= "red") +
 scale_x_reverse() +
 scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

This plot (image) is taking the minimum values and plotting them as green and maximum values as red. What I need help with is that I need colour palette to go from green to red (minimum to maximum) for every row of the plot (2 rows in this plot) rather than the whole plot.
For draft_mean=12.2, rf_pwr should be colour formatted from minimum to maximum for trim values.
For every value of draft_mean, I should be able to tell the trim values with lowest and highest rf_pwr.
I can plot individual draft_mean values to check, but all draft_mean values needs to be visualized together.

Comment: Perhaps scale "rf_pwr" to range 0-1 (`rf_pwr - min(rf_pwr))/(max(rf_pwr) - min(rf_pwr)`) by "draft_mean", and map `fill` to the scaled variable?

Comment: Thanks, Henrik :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scaled variable where min = 0 and max = 1 per group like this:

```
require(tidyverse)

# create toy data 
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
   draft_mean =sort(rep(c(12,12.2),11 )), 
   trim=rep(sample(seq(-1,1,length.out = 11), replace = F),2), 
   rf_pwr = sample(11000:13000,22)
)

# create a scaled variable per unique draft_mean (min = 0 and max = 1)
df <- df %>% group_by(draft_mean) %>% mutate(rf_scl = (rf_pwr- 
min(rf_pwr))/(max(rf_pwr)-min(rf_pwr)))

ggplot(df, aes(trim, draft_mean)) +
   geom_tile(aes(fill=rf_scl), color="black") +
   scale_fill_gradient(low= "green", high= "red") +
   scale_x_reverse() +
   scale_y_reverse()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed :D